# Graphics card not showing in Device Manager but it works

Tags: windows-7, windows, restore

Hey guys got a strange one.  I have a Windows 7 PC that was running fine up until last month when the OS took a nose dive.  I reloaded the OS back on there but now I cant get it to install the dedicated Radeon v3900 Card that was in there.

The device does not show up in the Device Manager but it works.  I have the DVI cable plugged in and I get picture and everything but in Device Manager it just says Standard VGA.  I tried to run the driver install but it just fails and crashes.  Everything else works fine so I am a little stumped.  Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by `I reloaded the OS back on there...`? Clean install, restore an old image? Is the GPU install-able on a different machine?

Comment: It was a clean install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue.  Since trying to install the Radeon drivers and having the installation crash I have installed an Nvidia card and after installing those drivers successfully and rebooting the PC everything is working fine now.  I am going to keep the ATI card for a later project.

Answer (score 1):

Standard vga means that it is not using the driver. Performance will definitely take a hit without the proper driver. You could try to manually install the driver by going to the standard vga properties then clicking update driver and just browse to the files instead of running the installer. Or possibly try to right click the driver installer and run as admin. You are using the latest driver from amd's website right?  If not definitely get the latest drivers from there

Comment: I am using the latest drivers and I have tried running them as Administrator.  The mobo has a standard VGA port on it and when I take the card out and use that it shows the same driver.  I also tried plugging the card into the other PCIE slot and same results.

Comment: You are definitely missing drivers. If this was a fresh install of windows make sure you have installed all of the motherboard drivers as well.

Comment: I made sure all of the drivers were installed successfully.  I have since resolved the issue